# background image is repeating, cant code it to stop

Tags: html, css

I need to get the background image in this page to show only once, no repeat, and to be centered, and about 500px down the page. I cant seem to write the code correctly. I know it's something like "background-image: norepeat", checked the WC3 page, it gave me some stuff, but it only broke the picture and it didnt show at all.

Here's the CSS part:

```
#wrapper {
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #d7fdc9;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background-image: url(../images/bkgd-image.gif);
}
```

Im unsure if you need the full HTML and CSS, so i just posted the small tidbit, cause i cant imagine you needing more.

If you do need it all, lmk, and ill post it. Ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
background: #d7fdc9 url(../images/bkgd-image.gif) no-repeat center 500px;
```

or the long way

```
background-image: url(../images/bkgd-image.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center 500px;
background-color:#d7fdc9;
```

and give your wrapper a height if it has nothing in it.

Comment: This did it, thanks Chris! Any way to keep the image from scrolling? I tried position: fixed; but that make the entire wrapper fixed.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;` will fix your background image

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` instead `background-image: norepeat`

```
body {
    background-image: url('paper.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Read more about property on W3School: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: This is actually what i recall from class, the repeat-y. For whatever reason it's not working. I know it's clearly something else i did and not your code, since i distinctly remember it being the same.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer What you are new to computer world? I just copy pasted the code from `W3C`. Its understood that you need to use `no-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

yeah maybe you're writing it wrong, it is:

```
background-image:url('../images/bkgd-image.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: Ty Chun, appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

Try insert `background-repeat: no-repeat;` into your css.

If you want create full page background : Try this

```
html {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```